# Checking input in Python 3 for certain format

Tags: python

For a school project I have to write a program that takes an input in the form of 
`Name Name Number Number` from a single input. For example:

```
John Smith 20 50
```

What would be the best way to check that:
 1. The input contains only 4 words/numbers
 2. The format is two words followed by two numbers
and if its not, return an error until its entered properly.

Edit:
I've managed to get it working to check for numbers in the right place using Anand's suggestion, but I can't seem to get it to restart the while if has more than 4 words. Thanks

```
def checkInput(question):
    while True:
        textInput = input(question)
        splitList = textInput.split()
        if len(splitList) !=4:
            print("Invalid Format, Please Try Again")
        try:
            a = float(splitList[2])
            a = float(splitList[3])
            return(textInput)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Format, Please Try Again")
            continue


output = checkInput("Question: ")
print(output)
```

Comment: Hi Adam,did you have tried anything so far?

Comment: homework zero effort question

Comment: Stackoverflow only helps people who have tried themselves.

Comment: @AlexPan actually no, as you can see below there is always somebody who goes for the rep ;)

Comment: I have written a solution, but would advice you try these things yourself, otherwise you would not be able to learn the language well

Comment: There are many ways to answer this question and we don't know what level you are at, what functions you have learned in class, how deep to go with the requirements. What do you mean by `word`, does it have to be a valid word? Valid in what language? English? Or is it just not numbers? or could it be numbers mixed with letters? What kind of letters? ASCII or Unicode? If you've been learning about strings you can check if they are alphanumeric or digits for example, or you can split them based on whitespace. Your teacher will expect you to use what you've learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3, you can do something like -

```
inp = input()
lst = inp.split(' ')
if len(lst) != 4:
    raise Error('some error')    # give some value inside the Error('')
try:
    a = int(lst[2])
    a = int(lst[3])
except ValueError:
    raise Error('some other error')   # give some value inside the Error('')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would I contain it in a while loop to repeat until no errors are raised? Ill have a go with what you posted and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I've edited the original post with what I've got to work so far. But I still cant manage to get the while statement to restart after receiving an input that is more or less than 4 words. Would I use another try/except function? Thanks

Comment: put a `continue` after your `print` in the if condition for more or less than 4 words.